# Adding distance markers to Leaflet track

Tags: leaflet, markers

I would like to add a kind of label every x km along a track.
`x` would be a parameter depending on the total distance, zero meaning no marker.
This is an example of track [fly 210420](https://www.rudyv.be/OSM/Map.html?map=PilotePrive/Itineraires/210420.xml).
I get it using the following code.

I can easily give the posts parameters (max 10) as URL parameters to the HTML script, for instance
`&D1=20 &Lat1=xx &Lon1=yy &D2=40 &Lat2=xx &Lon2=yy` ...
or if possible in a kind of array and put the labels (20, 40, ...) on a layer at given Lats and Lons.

How can I do that?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Open Street Map</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" >
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="OpenStreetMap.png">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.css" >
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/Leaflet.GraphicScale.min.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/stylesheet.css" >

</head>
<body>

    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-omnivore/v0.2.0/leaflet-omnivore.min.js"></script>
    <script src="src/Leaflet.GraphicScale.min.js"></script>
    <script>
function getUrlParameter(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');
    var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)');
    var results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return (results === null)? '' : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
};

function highlightFeature(e) {
    var layer = e.target;

    layer.setStyle({
        weight: 5,
        color: '#666',
        dashArray: '10 10',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    });

    if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera && !L.Browser.edge) {
        layer.bringToFront();
    }
}

function resetHighlight(e) {
    customLayer.resetStyle(e.target);
}


var Marker = L.icon({
iconUrl: 'Point.png',

iconSize:     [27, 32], // size of the icon
iconAnchor:   [13, 32], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
popupAnchor:  [0, -30] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
});
var Lon = getUrlParameter('Lon')
var Lat = getUrlParameter('Lat')
var starts = new L.LayerGroup();
L.marker([Lat,Lon], {icon: Marker}).bindPopup(Lat+'<br>'+Lon).addTo(starts);

// ****************** change colors sequentially  *****************

var colors = [
'#3388ff',
'#800000',
'#9a6324',
'#808000',
'#469990',
'#000075',
'#000000', 
'#e6194b',
'#f58231',
'#ffe119',
'#bfef45',
'#3cb44b',
'#42d4f4',
'#4363d8',
'#911eb4',
'#f032e6',
'#a9a9a9',
//'#fabed4',    Pink
//'#ffd8b1',    Apricot
//'#fffac8',    Beige
//'#aaffc3',    Mint
'#dcbeff',
//'#ffffff' White
];

var n = 0;
var customLayer = L.geoJson(null, {
  style: function(feature) {
    if (!feature.properties.id) {
      feature.properties.id = n++;
    }
    var iColor = feature.properties.id % colors.length;
    return { color: colors[iColor] };
  }, 
onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
  if (feature.properties.desc) {
    layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.desc);
  }
  layer.on({
      mouseover: highlightFeature,
      mouseout: resetHighlight
  });
}



});

        var map = new L.LayerGroup();
        var runLayer = omnivore.gpx("../"+getUrlParameter('map'), null, customLayer)
        .on('ready', function() {
        map.fitBounds(runLayer.getBounds());
    })
    .addTo(map);


            var osmLink = '<a href="https://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>'
        ;
         var osmUrl = 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            osmAttrib = '&copy; ' + osmLink + ' Contributors'
            ;
        var mbAttr = 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
                '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
                'Imagery © <a href="https://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
            mbUrl = 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiamFudXMwMDciLCJhIjoiY2l0azNvNjZlMDAzbTQ2bGk0dDFtaGhzcCJ9.8GAQYGpMFog62mRv17pGtA';

        var osmMap = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, {attribution: osmAttrib}),
            satellite  = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {id: 'mapbox.satellite',   attribution: mbAttr});           
            
         var Stamen_Terrain = L.tileLayer('https://stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/terrain/{z}/{x}/{y}.{ext}', {
            attribution: 'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
            subdomains: 'abcd',
            ext: 'png'
        });     
        var standard = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: 'Map data: &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>, <a href="http://viewfinderpanoramas.org">SRTM</a> | Map style: &copy; <a href="https://opentopomap.org">OpenTopoMap</a> (<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>)',
            maxZoom: 18
        });

        var map = L.map('map', {
            layers: [osmMap, starts, map],
        })
        .setView([49.21, 4.2], 8);

        var baseLayers = {  
            "OpenStreetMap": osmMap,                
            "OpenTopoMap": standard,
            "3D map" : Stamen_Terrain,
            "satellite": satellite,
        };

        L.control.layers(baseLayers).addTo(map);

        var graphicScale = L.control.graphicScale({
        position:  'bottomright',   
        fill: 'hollow',
        }).addTo(map);
    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved like this

```
var marker = new L.marker([getUrlParameter('Lat0'),getUrlParameter('Lon0')], { opacity: 0 }); 
marker.bindTooltip(getUrlParameter('D0')+"km", {permanent: true, offset: [0, 0] });
marker.addTo(map);
var marker = new L.marker([getUrlParameter('Lat1'),getUrlParameter('Lon1')], { opacity: 0 }); 
marker.bindTooltip(getUrlParameter('D1')+"km", {permanent: true, offset: [0, 0] });
marker.addTo(map);
...
var marker = new L.marker([getUrlParameter('Lat9'),getUrlParameter('Lon9')], { opacity: 0 }); 
marker.bindTooltip(getUrlParameter('D9')+"km", {permanent: true, offset: [0, 0] });
marker.addTo(map);
```

Still a small problem : the lablel is not close enough to the trace, I will open a new question.